# NodeJS: loading ES Modules and native addons in the same project

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, hunspell

Before the actual questions (see at the end), please let me show the steps that lead to that question through an example:

### Creating the project

```
tests$ mkdir esm && cd esm
tests/esm$ nvm -v
0.37.2
tests/esm$ nvm use v15
Now using node v15.6.0 (npm v7.5.6)
tests/esm$ node -v
v15.6.0
tests/esm$ npm -v
7.5.6
tests/esm$ npm init
package name: (esm) test-esm
entry point: (index.js)
```

**Installing [nodehun](https://github.com/Wulf/nodehun)**

```
tests/esm$ npm install nodehun
added 2 packages, and audited 3 packages in 11s
tests/esm$ npm ls
test-esm@1.0.0 tests/esm
└── nodehun@3.0.2
```

- dependencies of nodehun [here](http://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/nodehun)

**`index.js`**

```js
import { suggest } from './checker.js'
suggest("misspeling");
```

**`checker.js`**

```js
import Nodehun  from 'nodehun'
import fs from 'fs';

const affix       = fs.readFileSync('dictionaries/en_NZ.aff')
const dictionary  = fs.readFileSync('dictionaries/en_NZ.dic')
const nodehun     = new Nodehun(affix, dictionary)

export const suggest = (word) => hun_suggest(word);

async function hun_suggest(word) {
  let suggestions = await nodehun.suggest(word);
  console.log(suggestions);
}
```

To obtain the required **Hunspell dictionary** files (`aff`ix and `dic`tionary):

```
tests/esm$ mkdir dictionaries && cd dictionaries
tests/esm/dictionaries$ curl https://www.softmaker.net/down/hunspell/softmaker-hunspell-english-nz-101.sox > en_NZ.sox
tests/esm/dictionaries$ unzip en_NZ.sox en_NZ.aff en_NZ.dic
```

### Running the project

As per `nodejs` documentation ([Determining Module System](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system)) to support the `import` / `export`:

> Node.js will treat the following as [ES modules](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) when passed to `node` as the initial input, or when referenced by `import` statements within ES module code:
> • Files ending in `.js` when the nearest parent `package.json` file contains a top-level ["type"](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/packages.html#packages_type) field with a value of `"module"`.

We add **`"type": "module"`** field in the `package.json` file of the project.

**`package.json`**

```json
{
  ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  ...
}
```

**First Failed Run**

```sh
tests/esm$ node index.js
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".node" for tests/esm/node_modules/nodehun/build/Release/Nodehun.node
... omitted ...
at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:9) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

Digging a bit on the reason of the above error:

- in the documentation on how to [load addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_loading_addons_using_require), it refers to the use of `require`

> The filename extension of the compiled addon binary is **`.node`** (as opposed to `.dll` or `.so`). The require() function is written to look for files with the `.node` file extension and initialize those as dynamically-linked libraries.

- once you define your node project as a `"type": "module"`, `require` it [ceases to be supported](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_require) (as specified in *Interoperability with CommonJS*):

> Using `require` to load an ES module is not supported because ES modules have asynchronous execution. Instead, use import() to load an ES module from a CommonJS module.

**Temporary Solution**

After some time searching the documentation, I found a **temporary solution**: [Customizing ESM specifier resolution algorithm](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_customizing_esm_specifier_resolution_algorithm):

> The current specifier resolution **does not support all default behavior of the CommonJS loader**. One of the behavior differences is automatic resolution of file extensions and the ability to import directories that have an index file.
> The **`--experimental-specifier-resolution=[mode]`** flag can be used to customize the extension resolution algorithm.
> To enable the automatic extension resolution and importing from directories that include an index file use the `node` mode.

```sh
tests/esm$ node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node index.js
(node:XXXXX) ExperimentalWarning: The Node.js specifier resolution in ESM is experimental.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[
  'misspelling',
  'misspending',
  'misspeaking',
  'misspell',
  'dispelling',
  'misapplier',
  'respelling'
]
```

There are a some posts that get to this same resolution ([ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63460038/4352306), [ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63809041/4352306)).
However, using **experimental flags** does not seem a proper way to run your application on production.

**Failed Alternative with `esm` package**

From that point, several failed attempts have been tried to avoid the use of `--experimental-*` flags. Doing some search, I found some posts ([ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62454948/4352306), [ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57948898/4352306)) recommending the use of the `esm` package.

- [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) gets 1.3M downloads per week.
- According the read-me file in [GitHub](https://github.com/standard-things/esm#readme), it does not require any changes.

However, at this point, when I try this `node -r esm index.js`, a new error appears:

```sh
tests/esm$ npm install esm
added 1 package, and audited 4 packages in 709ms
tests/esm$ npm ls
test-esm@0.1.0 tests/esm
├── esm@3.2.25
└── nodehun@3.0.2
tests/esm$ node -r esm index.js
tests/esm/index.js:1
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: tests/esm/index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1125:13) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

The above could be due to a *reported issue* ([Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module / require() of ES modules is not supported](https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/868)).

- There is **[proposed patch](https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/868#issuecomment-594480715)** to fix it, although I do not know how to use it myself.

```js
const module = require('module');
module.Module._extensions['.js'] = function(module, filename) {
  const content = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
  module._compile(content, filename);
};
```

### Questions

1. Is there a (standard) way to use `import` / `export` (ES Modules) without incurring in issues with `import` **addons**?

   - Avoiding the use of the `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` flag.
2. Perhaps `esm` could be the solution to the above. Is there anything I am doing wrong with the usage `esm` package?

   - If it is a correct usage, is there a way to use [the proposed patch](https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/868#issuecomment-594480715) myself as a working around?

Any hints to help to solve it would be really appreciated.

**Note**: the final status of the example can be cloned from https://github.com/rellampec/test-esm.git

Comment: I _think_ you can do `import { createRequire } from 'module'; const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);` to get a `require` function inside the ESM to load the native module?

Comment: @loganfsmyth just pasted your code at the top of the `index.js` and retried `node -r esm index.js`: same error `ERR_REQUIRE_ESM` (btw, `node index.js` persists with the error `ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some ramblings trying to figure this out got to the root cause.

When using `node -r esm index.js`, the `esm` package does already all the work for your (as noted in other answers), and therefore (not mentioned in other answers):

- the `package.json` should be updated by **removing `"type:" "module"`** (as it creates unintended interactions between the native `node` ES Modules feature and the `esm` package you installed)

**Aside note:** if you tried to use `node` ES Modules and then you try to switch to `esm` package, it is very easy to miss this point.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem and fixed it this way:
https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#module_module_createrequire_filename

```
// The project is "type": "module" in package json
// createRequire is native in node version >= 12
import { createRequire } from 'module'; 
import path from 'path'; 
// Absolute path to node modules (or native addons)
const modulesPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');
// Create the require method
const localRequire = createRequire(modulesPath);
// require the native add-on
const myNativeAddon = localRequire('my-native-addon');
```

Comment: `function bindings(addonName, relPath="build/Debug") {
    const modulesPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), relPath, addonName);
    // Create the require method
    const localRequire = createRequire(modulesPath);
    // require the native add-on
    const myNativeAddon = localRequire(modulesPath); 
    return myNativeAddon;
}` This worked for me. Note how I am passing the same path to both createRequire and localRequire.

Comment: You sir are a hero. Sad that such a kludgy solution is needed. I despise the new ES module system, it makes everything so awkward and unintuitive... But there's no other way if even a SINGLE dependency of yours goes the ES route, you are dragged along with lol. Plus you can use async at the root level which is nice.